Как найти вхождение последнего символа подстроки в строку С++20?
Возникла проблема: допустим у меня есть строка already. Если я в этой строке попытаюсь найти подстроку read, с помощью функции std::string::find, то мне вернётся позиция 2 (Что не удивительно, так как find возвращает вхождение первого символа подстроки в строку). Но как сделать так, чтобы вернулась позиция 5 (То-есть вхождение последнего символа подстроки в строку)?

std::string::rfind?

Это не то. Оно ищет не символы наоборот, а вхождение строк наоборот. Если find возвращает первое вхождение подстроки, то rfind последнее.

А, ну просто прибавить длину подстроки к результату тогда?

Спасибо, andreymal

Только перед прибавлением не забудьте проверить, что результат не npos

До этого я уже догадался, но все равно спасибо вам, что вы заботитесь о моём коде, andreymal
